# Mouseover Slideshow

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, slideshow, onmouseover

So I have a webpage with one image on it (slicedImg_01). I would like to have that static picture animate randomly through a series of 6 pictures on mouseover. So far what I have will randomly generate pictures to the page, however it just creates a new image to the page and doesn't replace the original image. Here is what I have. Also, I am trying to avoid jquery. (slicedImg_02, slicedImg_03, etc.)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div >
<img  onmouseover="imgSwitch()" src="slicedImg_01.gif" height="50" width="50" id =  "pic">
</img>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:
    function imgSwitch(){

```
 var img = new Array("slicedImg_01.gif", "slicedImg_02.gif", "slicedImg_03.gif",  "slicedImg_04.gif", "slicedImg_05.gif", "slicedImg_06.gif");
    var i;
    //var pic = ""
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        var rand = img[Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length)];
        var image = document.getElementById("pic").src
         image = new Image();
        image.src = rand;
        document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is the line creating a new image `image = new Image();`. The code below should replace the current image with the randomly selected new image:

```
function imgSwitch(){
  var img = new Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg",  "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg");
  var rand = img[Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length)];
  document.getElementById("pic").src = rand;
}
```

Note the image names need to be replaced with yours.